# Get Data inside Json using a key

Tags: c#, json

I 'm working on a Xamarin Forms application, I m  using a rest service to get data from the server. I want to get a value inside the JSON. Response.content 's JSON is below.

```
{"Success":true,"ErrorMessages":[],"Data":{"text":"Yes","value":100}}
```

Comment: Deserialize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to Deserialize your json data by using library like [NewtonSoft.JSON/Json.NET](https://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net)  , example

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
void Example ()
{
    string json = @"{ Name: 'Bob', HairColor: 'Brown' }";
    var bob = JObject.Parse (json);
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} with {1} hair", bob["Name"], bob["HairColor"]);
}
```